# Sort String "13,5,8,4,2,1,9" in ascending order 1,2,4,5,8,9,13 in Java

Tags: java, sorting

How can I sort a string `"13,5,8,4,2,1,9"` in ascending order, to get `1,2,4,5,8,9,13`?

Comment: 9 upvotes for this question?

Comment: Strictly speaking, if you want 13 at the end (and not between 1 and 2) then you are sorting **numerically** not alphabetically.

Comment: -1 bad/ugly question, you do no want to sort Strings. Problem may comes from modelisation somewhere. Even if you recieved a string representation of an int list, you should have model it in another way I guess.

Comment: @Mattheiu: give the OP a break. Perhaps the string comes from user input like a dialog box.

Comment: So who's the winner?  Did any of these answers work for you?  If so, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 27):

- Split the string by commas
- Parse each substring into an integer
- Sort the resulting collection
- If you need the result to be a string (it's not clear), convert each integer back into a string and join them together with commas.

If any of those steps causes you difficulties, please be more specific.

Answer (score 14):

1. Split it into an array of items with `String.split()`.
2. Convert to an array of numbers with `Integer.valueOf()`.
3. Sort the array.
4. Concatenate it all back into a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: I'd use a StringBuilder; no need to incur the overhead of thread synchronization here.

Comment: +1 for mentioning method names; makes it the best answer most likely to lead to the questioner writing their own idiomatic code.

Answer (score 8):

As one liner, using Google Collections (updated with Kevin's suggestion)

```
Joiner.on(",").join(Ordering.natural().onResultOf(new Function<String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(String from) {
        return Integer.valueOf(from);
    }
}).sortedCopy(Arrays.asList("4,2,7,9,1".split(","))));
```

- Split using `String.split()`
- Transform to `Integer` using a `Function` (anyone know if there's a constant for this one somewhere?)
- Sort using a `TreeSet` and natural ordering
- Join the parts and transform back to a `String` using `Joiner`

(old version)

```
Joiner.on(',').join(
    Sets.newTreeSet(
        Iterables.transform(
            Arrays.asList("13,5,8,4,2,1,9".split(",")),
            new Function<String, Integer>() {
                @Override
                public Integer apply(String from) {
                    return Integer.parseInt(from);
                }}))));
```

Comment: Other ideas with GC/Guava: you could create an Ordering.natural().onResultOf(yourFunction), and use it like: ordering.sortedCopy(Splitter.on(',').split(input)).

Comment: Sounds like a nice syntax, I'll try it out some time.

Comment: Re: the Integer.valueOf() function, it will show up in Guava in a few months I think.

Comment: This is going to get so much smaller with Java 8's lambda's :)

Answer (score 6):

```
String s = "13,5,8,4,2,1,9";
String[] arr = s.split(",");
Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String>() {
   @Override public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
      return Integer.parseInt(s1) - Integer.parseInt(s2);
   }
});
s = Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll("[\\[ \\]]", "");
```

This solution uses:

- [`java.util.Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)
- [`java.util.Arrays`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) `sort` and `toString`
- [`String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) `split` and `replaceAll`
- [regular expression](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

I would tokenize the string using StringTokenizer,
parse the values (using Integer.parseInt),
then sort the results using Arrays.sort.
Lastly, re-create the string.

Comment: StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split  method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "13,5,8,4,2,1,9";
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(", ");
ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String token: tokens)
   ints.add(Integer.parseInt(token));

Collection.sort(ints);
String sortedStr = "";
for(int i = 0; i + 1 < ints.size(); ++i)
   sortedStr += ints.get(i) + ", ";
if (ints.size() > 0)
   sortedStr += ints.lastElement();
```

Might have some misspellings, but I think not. Also, add the appropriate imports yourself =)

Comment: well well, I actually had no idea StringTokenizer was deprecated. However, now I know =)

Answer (score 1):

So you have a string containing a comma-delimited set of integers that you need to sort and then output to a string? Try `split`-ting the string, `parse`-ing the integers, `sort`-ing the resulting array, and then `join`-ing the results together

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8+

If you are using Java 8 you can use streams to sort like so :

```
String str = "13,5,8,4,2,1,9";
String sortedString =
        Arrays.stream(str.split(","))             //split with ','
                .map(Integer::valueOf)            //convert your strings to ints
                .sorted()                         //sort 
                .map(String::valueOf)             //convert them back to string
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));//1,2,4,5,8,9,13
```

---

If you want an sorted array you can also use :

```
Integer[] sortedInts =
        Arrays.stream(str.split(","))    //split with ','
                .map(Integer::valueOf)   //convert your strings to ints
                .sorted()                //sort
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);//[1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 13]
```

The idea is the same as [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2543414/5558072) explanation.

Answer (score 0):

ok you can try this one it work in all case.

```
package com.java;


import java.util.*;

public class cd
{      
  public static void main(String s[])
  {  
        Collections col;
        List l = sort(s);

        System.out.println("\nStrings sorted List ...");
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        {
              System.out.println((String)l.get(i));
        }

        int ints[] = {
                                719, 2, -22, 401, 6
                                };

        Integer in[] = new Integer[ints.length];            
        for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i++)
        {
              in[i] = new Integer(ints[i]);
        }

        l = sort(in);
        System.out.println("\nIntegers sorted List ...");

        for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i++)
        {
              System.out.println((Integer)l.get(i));
        }
}

public static List sort(Object o[])
{
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
        al.add(i, o[i]);
        List list = Collections.synchronizedList(al);
        Collections.sort(list);
        return list;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using `java.util.Scanner`

```
public class SortString {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        // Read integers using Scanner...
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( "13,5,8,4,2,1,9" ).useDelimiter(",");

        // Put them in a Integer list
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while( scanner.hasNextInt() ){
            list.add( scanner.nextInt() );
        }
        // And sort it
        Collections.sort( list );
        System.out.println( list );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is one way to sorting.

```
package com.java;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Collections;


public class b{

public static void main(String[] args) {
//create an ArrayList object

ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();


//Add elements to Arraylist

arrayList.add("9");
arrayList.add("3");
arrayList.add("5");
arrayList.add("2");
arrayList.add("4");

Collections.sort(arrayList);


//display elements of ArrayList

System.out.println("ArrayList elements after sorting in ascending order : ");

for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++)

System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));



}

}
```

Comment: @c0mrade He doesn't. He demos the sorting.

Comment: @extraneon I know he doesn't that's why I ask, this guy is probably looking something else to sort every now and then ..

Comment: @Sanjeev - sorting Strings will NOT work for this problem. Using the numbers given in the question this code will return `1 13 2 4 5 8 9`

Comment: @Sanjeev- Your program does not achieve what has been asked for.

Answer (score -1):

```
class SplitStr
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    try
    {
      String str=args[0]+","+args[1];    //marge two string in one
      String sArr[]=str.split(",");
      int slen=sArr.length;
      int iArr[]=new int[slen];
      int temp;
      for(int i=0;i<slen;i++)
      {
       iArr[i]=Integer.parseInt(sArr[i]);   //convert String into integer array

      }
      for(int i=0;i<slen;i++)
      {
        for(int j=i+1;j<slen;j++)
        {
          if(iArr[i]>=iArr[j])
          {
            temp=iArr[i];
            iArr[i]=iArr[j];
            iArr[j]=temp;
          }
        }
      }
      for(int i=0;i<slen;i++)
      {
        System.out.println(" "+iArr[i]);
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("input error "+e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Bash is SO powerful :-)

```
numbers="1, 2, 9, 4, 7, 5" ; for number in $(echo "$numbers") ; do echo "$number" | tr -d ", "; done | sort | tr "\n" "," ; echo ""
```